# D3 table with Objects along x axis, fields along y axis. Cell coloured if field condition is met

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

My goal is to create a chart with d3 that has a list of objects along the x-axis and field values on the y axis.

I'm going to colour a cell if a field meets a condition for the object. (i.e its null)

Is there any good examples available? I've been working off the les Miserables example but it doesn't fir the requirements. I'm new at d3 and am struggling to find an example to start off with.

I don't have permission to provide data from the dataset so I'll give an example.

I have 4 objects [ObjectA, ObjectB, ObjectC, ObjectD]. All four objects are stored in mongodb and have the following fields [name, address, number, age]. I need to create a chart that highlights the changes between the objects based on the fields.

i.e if the only difference between A and B is the name field and the only difference between B and C is the age they should be highlighted like in my crude table below

```
name     

address

number                 X

age                             X
          A            B        C          D
```

Comment: You might want to provide an example of the data

Comment: Thank you. I will provided a simple example as I dont have permission to share the data

Comment: Sounds like [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a simplified version of this d3 example that [visualizes characters in Les Mis](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/miserables/).

Comment: I was working off that example but it doesn't fit the requirements I have. i.e the x and y axis contain the same values. I dont think my javascript and d3 skills are not good enough to make the modification to the code to get it working. Perhaps I should spend some more time examining the code.

Comment: Looking at some of the examples..Perhaps a scatterplot would work. It looks as if the dataset must contain numbers however as opposed to json objects with text values. Perhaps it could be a nice approach to try?

Comment: The X and Y axes do contain the same values in that example, right? d3 can handle qualitative scales just fine -- use an ordinal scale instead of a linear scale. Here's a much simpler example of an ordinal scale on the x axis: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885304

Comment: So you can use ordinal scales for both axes